# Enhance Video Card

Tags: windows-7, windows, graphics-card, bios

I would like to know about ways to enhance a video (graphic) card performance and/or increase its memory (perhaps virtualizing memory, I personally don’t know if it’s possible).

For over-clocking or flashing its bios I know it depends on the video card model. Anyway, I have an Nvidia Geforce 9400M on my laptop (which I want to enhance, since I found not viable to replace it with a new model) (the laptop processor is an Intel Core 2 Duo T9300, its installed phisical memory is 4 GB, has 100 GB of free HD space).

Update:
Do you know a way of virtualizing or emulating graphic cards??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know about ways to
>   enhance a video (graphic) card
>   performance

You have 2 choices:

1. Overclock your graphics card
2. Upgrade the graphics card

**Overclocking:** Overclocking is probably the most common way of boosting performance. While it is possible to overclock on stock hardware, you are likely to run into the wall sooner than later. Adding to this is the fact that your is a laptop graphics processor and space comes at a premium in laptops, I'd recommend against this.

**Upgrading:** This may or may not be possible/feasible - depending on your laptop manufacturer, the motherboard, the way the graphics card is attached.

Other than the above two,

**Increase its memory:** Increasing the amount of memory on a graphics card will NOT increase performance, since the memory is used to store texture data and not for processing.

Comment: The amount of memory might not be related directly to graphic card performance, but I think it's directly related with 3d capabilities.

Comment: @Mario: no, that's not right. It doesn't matter if a low end card has 128MB of graphics memory or 4GB - it will not improve the card's processing ability

Comment: Look at it this way.  It doesn't matter if you have a shotglass or a bathtub, there's only so quickly you can drink through a straw.

Comment: @Sathya, I never said I wanted to have a really low end GPU + More Memory. I just wanted to said that memory helps on 3d and on rendering process (to a capable 3d GPU). Obviously the GPU clock rate and bandwidth must be paired by the amount and speed of memory (if that isn't the case there could be bottlenecks).

Comment: Have you heard about virtualizing or emulating GPUs?? I think that's where my research is tending.

Comment: @Mario: Virtualization is used to simulate machines or components less powerful than the one that is doing the virtualization.  GPUs in particular are optimized for doing parallel operations.  The 9400M has 16 processors... 8 times the number your CPU does.

Comment: @R. Bemrose that was what I thaught since I'm a VMWare fan, but today I found a web page that talks about a tool (it's old), but it seems that could emulate more powerfull GPUs than the installed ones (increasing the amount of memory (uses some of the free installed RAM for this) and the 3d proccessing of the graphic card with the CPU help). This is the link (http://www.3dfxzone.it/dir/tools/3d_analyze/download/). I don't know if there's an actual tool that could do that.

Comment: This tool might be a fake though.. but it was supported by a 3dfx gamming community.

Comment: @Mario 3D analyze doesn't emulate anything, it incorrectly reports the (in)capabilities of a graphics processor. Using 3D Analyze may cause a game or a program to run, but the end results are quite unpredictable and it sure won't run faster

Comment: @Sathya I haven't tryed it yet, but what many gaming posts say is that it emulates 3D capabilities on a not good 3D capable environment for running a single game. (http://www.computingunleashed.com/how-to-runplay-latest-games-without.html) (http://www.theprohack.com/2009/03/using-3d-analyzer-to-play-games-without.html)

Comment: Well, thanks a lot for your time and all your comments. I decided not to risk my laptop hardware while trying to over-clock it unnecessarily (it's still ok for what I need it to do). I’ll wait a little and on a near future target to a new laptop with richer graphics and higher processing capabilities.

Comment: @Mario I have to say that posts are "misleading" as the the software doesn't emulate them. When a game engine asks the card for its capabilities, the software kicks in and reports the unsupported features as available. So the game thinks the card is supported as runs them. Now what happens when the missing capabilities are used - that depends - some games crash, others run them without the *bling*-*bling*.

Comment: @Sathia that was too good to be truth, I was supposing that there wasn't that kind of magic, thanks a lot.